# Laravel Blade Composor/Creator override

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am intending to provide a default set of variables to various blade views with the ability to override them later. For example

a.blade.php

```
<p>a.blade</p>
<p>{{ $foo }}</p>
@include('b')
@include('b', ['bar' => 'bar as param'])
```

b.blade.php

```
<p>b blade</p>
<p>{{ $bar }}</p>
```

When I use `View::creator`, it allows me to use `->with()` at runtime to recompose my views and override the ones bound in the creator. If I use `View::composer`, this is not the case.

So given the below creator

```
View::creator('a', function ($view) {
    $view->with(['foo' => 'foo as CREATED']);
});
```

I am able to then use (in a route Closure for example)

```
return view('a')->with('foo', 'foo from composition');

// Expected a.blade foo from composition (excluding inclusion of b)
// Actual   a.blade foo from composition (excluding inclusion of b)
```

But I am not able to use

```
return view('a', ['foo' => 'foo from composition']);

// Expected a.blade foo from composition (excluding inclusion of b)
// Actual   a.blade foo as CREATED (excluding inclusion of b)
```

This isn't so much of an issue here as I can use `->where()` but my problem lies in the fact that I can no longer use blade directives `@include` or `@component` within my templates.

So given the above example, add a creator for a

```
View::creator('b', function ($view) {
    $view->with(['bar' => 'bar AS CREATED']);
});
```

Then in a.blade.php as above

```
@include('b')
@include('b', ['bar' => 'bar as param'])

// Expected
//    b.blade bar AS CREATED
//    b.blade bar as param

// Actual
//    b.blade bar AS CREATED
//    b.blade bar AS CREATED
```

So I'm looking for a way I can achieve the ability to provide defaults for variables to views and then override them with these syntax

```
view('a', ['foo' => 'bar']);
@include('a', ['foo' => 'bar'])
@component('a', ['foo' => 'bar'])
```